# Match subdirectories in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to match a URL like: http://xy.com/test/abcd to a php script named test.php

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.* test.php [L]
```

This matches fine when I make a request with curl like:

```
curl http://xy.com/test123
```

But it the rule does not seem to match the following call (getting a http not found)

```
curl http://xy.com/test/1234
```

The latter case is what I want to implement a RESTful API. How do I have to define my rule to match this?

Comment: Does the description body of the 404 response say "The requested URL /test/1234 was not found", or is the URL it claims it was looking for different? (e.g. `/test.php/1234`)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think your rule in the second example tries to find /test/test.php

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.* /test.php [L]
```